# Will the save method in a Cakephp model class choose between creating and updating a record?

Tags: php, cakephp

Basically, I want to achieve the same thing as [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in MySQL.

Here's a contrived example:

```
$rec = array('Foo' => array(
  'id' => 999,  // Assume there isn't already a record with this id
  'website' => 'google'
));
$this->Foo->save($rec);

// save with different 'website' value
$rec['Foo']['website'] = 'stackoverflow';
$this->Foo->save($rec);
```

Does the last line update the record that was created just a few lines up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you call `save()`, supplying a record with an existing `id` (or whatever is the primary key), it will update, otherwise it will create a new record.

So in your case, yes, it would update the record that was first created at the top.

**Update**

Here's [the supporting documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data):

> Creating or updating is controlled by
>   the model's id field. If $Model->id is
>   set, the record with this primary key
>   is updated. Otherwise a new record is
>   created.

Under the documentation for `Model::save()`.